# Do most people have no idea where their food comes from or how it’s made?

Tags: agriculture, vegetarianism

[Mercy For Animals article](https://mercyforanimals.org/shocking-new-study-finds-public-knows-nothing)

> According to U.K.-based paper The Herald [Plymouth], a new study shows most people have no idea where their food comes from or how it’s made.
>
> Vegan organization Viva! commissioned the study, which surveyed 2,000 people ...

To summarize from the the already brief article where most animal products come from: (1) [factory farms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_animal_farming). Furthermore, the "how", (2) dairy cows have to be impregnated in order to produce milk, (3) male chicks on egg farms are culled (usual/majority practice) or that (4) most animals are slaughtered at a relatively young age (less than 30% of their potential).

The link is broken that should provide the actual study. Can anyone prove that this survey exists or find another survey (of equivalent size showing that most people in industrialized countries like the US and UK have little "idea where their food comes from or how it’s made")?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108651/discussion-on-question-by-adamaero-do-most-people-have-no-idea-where-their-food).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, Viva!, a UK-based pro-vegan charity conducted a survey in 2016.

Here is their [press release](https://www.viva.org.uk/what-we-do/about-us/media-centre/media-releases/viva-survey-millions-people-have-no-idea-how-their) dated four days before the cited article.

Note, this was not a scientific study, published in a peer-reviewed journal. It was a survey commissioned by a political lobby group used to get media attention.

They report that the surveyed people changed their minds after "learning more", suggesting the poll was an example of [push-polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_poll).

> But the study, of 2,000 people, commissioned by vegan campaigning charity, Viva! found that after learning more about the legal treatment of farmed animals in the UK, almost half would consider cutting back on the meat, eggs and dairy products.

Its results should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: I would put emphasis on "after learning more about the legal treatment" which is not the same as "idea where their food comes from"